# Async setTimeout on Promise based? Promise {<pending>} Error

Tags: javascript, timer, promise, async-await, settimeout

So, I'm trying to bring my function work with async timers logic, where I need to execute `computeResult` (func for example) after the timer is stop. To get the setTimeout async logic under control I had used the Promise based `asyncFunc` function, but it always return me `Promise {<pending>}` when I used it.

Where is my fall in this case? Thank you.

P.S.
I also see the various posts on this topic on SoF, but it does not help me. Do not block my question just to grow up your EXP on SoF

```
const computeResult = () => {
  return 'sdas'
}

const asyncFunc = () => new Promise(
   r => setTimeout(r, 1000))
     .then(() => computeResult()
);

export default asyncFunc
```

Comment: Yes, a promise will indeed return a promise,.. You either `await` this, or use the `then` callback.

Comment: @Keith my knowledges with promises are poor ...can you describe it on my case more widely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You write all right in this case, except one little think. You forgot to execute the `Promise` after it has been resolved, that's why it stuck on `<pending>` state.

So, in another words just write after the `asyncFunc` invoke the `.then` tail in like next way `asyncFunc().then(your_sersult => ddoSomething(your_sersult))`

That's all. You will get what you want :)

You can read more about it on the MDN site:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: "*You forgot to execute the Promise after it has been resolved*" - huh? One cannot "execute" a promise, it's not a function. What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure what your trying to do,.

But the following might be what your after.

```js
const computeResult = () => {
   return 'sdas'
}

const asyncFunc = () => new Promise(resolve => 
   setTimeout(() => resolve(computeResult()), 1000)
);

console.log("Wait for computeResult");
asyncFunc().then(r => console.log(r));
```